# wxWidgets CallAfter waking main UI thread on macOS?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, wxwidgets

I am getting "UI API called from background thread" errors under wxWidgets master from GitHub under macOS.

```
UI API called from background thread Group
file:///DeveloperLibs/wxWidgets-3.1.3/src/osx/cocoa/evtloop.mm: runtime: UI API called from background thread: -[NSApplication postEvent:atStart:] must be used from main thread only

#0  0x00000001004e5908 in wxGUIEventLoop::WakeUp() at /DeveloperLibs/wxWidgets-3.1.3/src/osx/cocoa/evtloop.mm:390
#1  0x00000001004651fd in wxApp::WakeUpIdle() at /DeveloperLibs/wxWidgets-3.1.3/src/osx/carbon/app.cpp:439
#2  0x00000001001d0cf7 in wxWakeUpIdle() at /DeveloperLibs/wxWidgets-3.1.3/src/common/appbase.cpp:1108
#3  0x00000001003a6a03 in wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent(wxEvent*) at /DeveloperLibs/wxWidgets-3.1.3/src/common/event.cpp:1318
#4  0x000000010017a09c in void wxEvtHandler::CallAfter<myPanel::Finish()::$_1>(myPanel::Finish()::$_1 const&) at /DeveloperLibs/wxWidgets-3.1.3/include/wx/event.h:3668
#5  0x0000000100179fba in myPanel::Finish() at /Volumes/Macintosh HD04/Users/rich/Projects/thing/myPanel.cpp:88
```

.... lines beneath here are just thread/_pthread_start stuff that isn't relevant.

Inside `myPanel::Finish()` (which is called by the thread when it finishes), I am using:

```
void myPanel::Finish()
{
  this->GetEventHandler()->CallAfter([this]()
  {
    stopButton->Disable();
    GoToResultsPanel();
  });
}
```

The issue is not the code in my lambda but the actual CallAfter call since it calls `wxWakeUpIdle()`, which then ends up in `wxApp::WakeUpIdle()`, which ends up in `wxGUIEventLoop::WakeUp()`, calling `[NSApp postEvent:event atStart:FALSE];`

In this way my background thread is waking the UI thread. The documentation for `wxEvtHandler::CallAfter` states:

*Notice that it is safe to use CallAfter() from other, non-GUI, threads, but that the method will be always called in the main, GUI, thread context.*

This does not seem to be the case here? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: BTW This is under macOS Catalina. Under macOS Sierra and with wxWidgets 3.1.3 I do not get a runtime warning about the identical code. The evtloop.mm code is identical but produces no warnings under this older macOS!

Comment: I'm afraid the implementation of `CallAfter()` inside wx needs to be modified, but if we can't call `[NSApp postEvent:atStart:]` any longer from the worker threads, I have no idea how are we supposed to pass events to the main thread from them.

Comment: Yes, the warning seems wrong. From a quick search, the same issue is reported for glfw at https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1588. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428710-postevent state that it's fine to do what wxWidgets is doing, so I am going to ignore the warning for now and hope App Store submission succeeds.

Comment: I didn't realize it was just a warning, I thought it was a (fatal) error. If it's only a warning, I think it can indeed be ignored, at least for now...

Comment: It's a "runtime issue" reported in Xcode when you run it under the debugger. I am not sure how much gravity these carry. Thanks as always.